# Is there any way to create an array until user enters a specific number?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

When we create an array with unknown size then we use `malloc()` function.

Here is the code when I want to take the array size from user as an input.

```
int* ptr, len;
printf("Please enter the size number:");
scanf_s("%d", &len);

ptr = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the %d. number: ", i+1);
        scanf_s("%d", ptr + i);
    }
```

**But here is the question**
I want to build an application where user doesn't indicate any size value and enters the numbers so that place them into an array. Array is filling but hasn't got any limits. It hasn't allocated any memory initially like my code above. Only limit is that user enters a specific number (say -5) then, array is being stopped. And prints out the values.

In essence: I am looking for memory allocation but allocation will be decided on specific user input.

**Realloc edit that runs the code infnitely and never displays the array**

```
int i = 0,ctr=0;
int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
do
{
    printf("Enter the %d. value: \n",i+1);
    scanf_s("%d", ptr + i);
    ctr += 1;
    ptr = (int*)realloc(ptr, (i + 2) * sizeof(int));
    i += 1;
} while (*(ptr+i)!=-1);
```

Comment: You can use realloc to reallocate an array. Another approach is to use a list. But in the last case you will have only a sequential access to elements of a list.

Comment: I tried to program with realloc but loop is running infinitely even though I give it a condition.

Comment: It runs indefinitely, because your `while` condition looks at the number that isn't entered yet because you increase `i` just before it.

Comment: Consider using a linked list.

Comment: @EmanuelP when I saw it I laughed so hard. Well thank you sir. Thats just it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *ptr,n;
    ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // 
    int i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        puts("Enter a number");
        scanf(" %d",&n);// Take the value
        if(n == -5) //
        {
            *(ptr + i) = n; //if you don't wish to add -5 to your array remove this 
                // statement and following i++
            i++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            *(ptr + i) = n;
            ptr = realloc(ptr,(i+2)*sizeof(int));// reallocating memory and 
                           // passing the new pointer as location in memory can 
                            // change during reallocation.
            i++;
        }
    }
    int end = i;// Saving the number of elements.
    for(i=0;i<end;i++)
        printf(" %d\n",ptr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very simple, easy to understand. Thank you. Moreover, my code was actually correct too but due to misspelling the "i" statement I couldn't get the result.

Comment: @Belgrad, Yeah, I noticed that, but wanted to give you something self-explanatory. A suggestion, Try using comments to describe what you are doing. It will help with these small mistakes, for both short and long term. And try reading this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I can never quit asking unproperly organized post :) I always try to find the right way to ask it to you all but every time I ask I recieve pretty angry feedbacks. Thanks for this blog post it'll be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard function `realloc` or define a list. In the last case the access to elements of a list will be sequantil.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function `realloc` can be used to enter a sequence of numbers terminated by a sentinel value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int *p = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    int allocation_failed = 0;
    const int Sentinel = -1;

    printf( "Enter a sequence of values (%d - exit): ", Sentinel );

    for (int value; !allocation_failed         &&
                    scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 &&
                    value != Sentinel; )
    {
        int *tmp = realloc( p, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( *p ) );

        if (!( allocation_failed = tmp == NULL ))
        {
            p = tmp;
            p[n++] = value;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", p[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( p );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a sequence of values (-1 - exit): 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Pay attention to that you may not use the same pointer in a call of realloc like for example

```
int *p = realloc( p, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( *p ) );
```

because in general the function `realloc` can return a null pointer. In this case the address of the already allocated memory will be lost due to reassigning the pointer `p` will a null pointer.